# Taking inverse of a function that contains exponential term

Tags: functions

Consider we are given such a function

$$f(x) = 2^{2x-1}+3$$

How does one find $f^{-1}(x)$? Here I noticed that it is a bit different to take inverse of exponential terms. My attempt is as follows

Let $y = 2^{2x-1} +3$

$$ y - 3 = 2^{2x-1}$$

$$2y-6 = 2^{2x}$$

However, I dont think that is how exactly it works. Could you assist me with what I'm missing?

Regards

Comment: Looks good.  Now take the $\log()$ of both sides.

Comment: @Michael Are we supposed to take the log? I dont also know that.

Comment: Yea, you take the log to deal with the exponent.

Comment: @DonThousand Cannot we also just substitute $2^{2x}$ in $f(x)$?

Comment: What do you mean? How would you do that?

Comment: @DonThousand Nevermind, how do we take logarithm?

Comment: I could give you the answer for this specific example, but I think learning how logarithms work in general will serve you better long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Note that $2^{2x} >0$ and thus you can always apply the $\ln$ function (as mentioned-hinted in the comments). But, you also need that $2y-6 > 0 \Leftrightarrow y > 3$ since you apply the $\ln$ to that side as well of course. Taking this constrict into consideration, it is :

$$\ln(2y-6) = \ln 2^{2x} \Leftrightarrow \ln(2y-6) = 2x \ln 2 \Leftrightarrow  x = \frac{\ln(2y-6)}{\ln 4}$$

Now, interchange $x \leftrightarrow y$ and yield :

$$y = \frac{\ln(2x-6)}{\ln 4} \implies f^{-1}(x) = \frac{\ln(2x-6)}{\ln 4}$$

Don't forget that it must be $2x-6 >0 \Leftrightarrow x > 3$ and $y >3 \implies f(x) >3$ from the initial constrict.